# Shuffle an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I need an 2d array [9,16] with 144 numbers from 1->36 in random order (so each number is repeated 4 times).

Comment: It sounds more like you want a *shuffle* algorithm. The numbers themselves are not random at all - just their order. I suggest editing the question to clarify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
sourcearr = array();
for(i = 0; i < 36; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
      sourcearr[i+j] = i;
   }
}

sourcearr = shuffle(sourcearr)

k = 0;
myrandarr = array();
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    myrandarr[i] = array();
    for(j = 0; j < 16; j++){
        myrandarr[i][j] = sourcearr[k++];
    }
}
```

where you use [shuffle](http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle).

Comment: I forgot to say that each number is repeated 4 times, it isn't just random.

Comment: So there is nothing such as: Enumerable.Range(1,36)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't care about the distribution, just store the results of

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*36) + 1
```

for each element of the array

Comment: This won't repeat each number 4 times however.

Answer (score 0):

How's about:

```
var source = array();
var shuffled = array();

for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  for(var j=0; j<36;j++)
  {
    source[i*j] = j+1;
  }
}

while( source.length > 0 )
{
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*source.length);
  var element = source.splice(index,1);
  shuffled.push(element);
}
```